# Import from child directory in ghci session (import modules from tests in yesod)

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, ghci, cabal-dev

When you create a scaffolded site in yesod, it puts tests into separate directory like this:

```
YourProj/
YourProj/SomeModule.hs
YourProj/Handlers/FooHandler.hs
...
YourProj/tests/main.hs
YourProj/tests/FooTests.hs
```

So, now I want to fire ghci and import some code from `YourProj/tests/main.hs` or `YourProj/tests/FooTests.hs` to play with. How do I do it? I tried:

```
cabal-dev ghci
> :set -itests
> :load tests/TestImport.hs
tests/TestImport.hs:15:8:
    Could not find module `Control.Monad.IO.Class'
    It is a member of the hidden package `transformers-0.3.0.0'.
    Perhaps you need to add `transformers' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

So, while I succeeded adding subdirectory, I still have problems because of different cabal configuration of `build-depends` parameter in cabal file for test-suite.

How would I launch cabal-dev ghci and import some code from tests in Yesod?

Comment: Ok, I went and manually added build-depends lines from test-suite into main build-depends section, now it complains about "Not in scope: `$'".

Comment: You just need to import `Prelude`, the `cabal` file turns on `NoImplicitPrelude` by default.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman thanks, it all works fine now! I'll write an answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is this:

1. add all missing modules inside your cabal file from `build-depends` of your test-suite into `build-depends` of your app on top.
2. run `cabal-dev ghci` inside app's root and do `:set -itests`

You should then be able to do something like `:load tests/EntriesTest.hs` fine.